# PHP 8.0 - method_exists on non-object causes Fatal TypeError

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand in the [Breaking Changes for PHP 7.4 to 8.0](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php) what is causing the below line to throw a Fatal TypeError.  Obviously, I know it isn't correct but need clarity on what is causing it.  Perhaps it has something to do with the php.ini default value changes?  I don't get any errors using PHP 7.4.

```php
echo method_exists(false, 'pre_setup') . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: `method_exists(object|string $object_or_class, string $method): bool` - `false` is neither an object nor a string - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Comment: @AD7six that sounds like it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php  : `function_exists(string $function): bool` is what you are probably looking for

Comment: In my actual use case, the first argument passed to `method_exists` is a variable that **can** be `false` or an instance of a number of different classes.  I think what occurred pre-8.0 is that the boolean was implicitly converted to a string and then that string was searched for as a class.  This corresponds to [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php#119415) on the `method_exists` documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why it isn't listed anywhere in the breaking changes (unless I'm missing something). It certainly seems like one.

The change was [Bug #79462](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79462) being fixed, which aligned the behaviour of `method_exists` and `property_exists`. The decision was to go with the stricter of the two behaviours, and raise a `TypeError` on invalid arguments.

It's listed in the [PHP 8 changelog](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-8.php), although I can see why that would be hard to track down.

One of the Symfony core team opened a PHP bug for it here: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79623, so you're definitely not the only person that's been affected.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping/looking/expecting to find.  I haven't ever had to dig into the actual changelog for PHP releases (oops) as their migration guides are usually quite good.  Thank you kindly for finding this information.  Plenty of ways to fix this on my end but I wanted to ensure I understood what changed first in case that influenced my direction.